# Expect doesn't seem to work outside a tty in a particular context

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I've been trying to use expect, and it doesn't seem to work outside a tty in a particular context

It stems from trying to invoke the `makepkg` command *non-interactively* to build a package

```sh
$ makepkg -Ccfi --noconfirm
==> Installing package test-delta with pacman -U...

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to re
ad from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
==> WARNING: Failed to install built package(s).
```

Although I was able to invoke it properly with the following:

```sh
$ sudo -S -v <<< $'password\n'
$ source makepkg -Ccfi --noconfirm
```

I was still having similar troubles with password prompts when executing non-Bash programs. And what I thought would be an easy fix turned out not to work consistently... I need this generalized solution to work properly

The following is the expect script...

```sh
cat > run.sh <<"EOF"
expect -c 'spawn makepkg -Ccfi --noconfirm; expect "*password*"; send "password\n"; interact'
EOF
```

And it runs successfully on the terminal, installing the package

```sh
$ ./run.sh
...
==> Installing package test-delta with pacman -U...
[sudo] password for op:
loading packages...
warning: test-delta-1.0.0-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) test-delta-1.0.0-1

Total Installed Size:  0.00 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                            [##############################] 100%
...
```

Running the script on the tty seemed to work. However, this script was actually being executed by [`toast`](https://github.com/stepchowfun/toast), a sort of task runner mixed with Docker, and it would fail on there. (I did *try* to simulate Toast's behavior in bash and *wasn't* able to get it to fail in any way) The output looks like this when I try to run it through Toast:

```sh
➤ toast --shell
[INFO] Ready to run 2 tasks: init and main.
[INFO] Running task init…
[INFO] Running task main…
spawn makepkg -Ccfi --noconfirm
==> Making package: test-delta 1.0.0-1 (Sat 29 May 2021 01:58:26 AM UTC)
...
==> Finished making: test-delta 1.0.0-1 (Sat 29 May 2021 01:58:27 AM UTC)
==> Installing package test-delta with pacman -U...

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for op:
[INFO] Preparing a shell…
[op@9205d39656e4 scratch]$ pacman -Qi test-delta
error: package 'test-delta' was not found
```

I tried to simulate it's failing behavior manually for those that don't have the program installed. So I try to run without an attachment to current tty

```sh
# https://superuser.com/a/1430883
(setsid ./run.sh) </dev/null |& cat
```

The above does not fail, so I also tried the following to make it fail

```sh
(setsid ./run.sh) <>/dev/null
```

Both unexpectedly worked, so I looked at toast and it seemed to execute commands [like this](https://github.com/stepchowfun/toast/blob/4e781b8bc68877676bf6aa96ad60cf729c6a540e/src/docker.rs#L143).

So I try to use `sh` as well...

```sh
sh -c '(setsid ./run.sh) </dev/null |& cat'
```

AH (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻. This command succeeds while Toast fails? How does the command ran within Toast fails? I'm not sure what to do at this point. Some other tricks like `unbuffer -p` didn't seem to change things either...

I don't think it's due to any process namespaces created by Docker? I don't know what to guess at this point, I don't think Toast is doing anything special? I recon others have had similar problems that may be familiar with this issue - but if you wish to reproduce this on your own, I have the following setup in a directory:

You can replicate this with this `toast.yml` file

```yaml
image: archlinux
default: main
tasks:
  init:
    command: |
      set -Eeuo pipefail
      pacman -Syu --noconfirm base-devel sudo man-db expect

      sed -ie 's/# %sudo/%sudo/g' /etc/sudoers
      groupadd sudo

      useradd -m op -s /bin/bash -G sudo
      chpasswd <<< 'op:password'

  main:
    dependencies: [ init ]
    cache: false
    user: op
    mount_paths:
      - .
    command: |
      ./run.sh
```

This `PKGBUILD` file

```sh
# Maintainer: Edwin Kofler <edwin@kofler.dev>
pkgname='test-delta'
pkgver='1.0.0'
pkgrel='1'
pkgdesc='Desc'
arch=('any')
license=('unknown')
depends=(bash)

# prepare() {
#   :
# }

# build() {
#   :
# }

# check() {
#   :
# }

package() {
    mkdir "$pkgname-$pkgver"
    cd "$pkgname-$pkgver"

    mkdir -p "$pkgdir/usr/bin"
    cat > "$pkgdir/usr/bin/test-delta" <<< "echo 'WORKING WORKING WORKING WORKING' -------------------"
    chmod +x "$pkgdir/usr/bin/test-delta"
}
```

and this `run.sh` file

```sh
expect -c 'spawn makepkg -Ccfi --noconfirm; expect "*password*"; send "password\n"; interact'
```

By running `toast --shell` in the same directory...

```sh
$ toast --shell
...
[INFO] Preparing a shell…
[op@69bee81d643f scratch]$ pacman -Qi test-delta
error: package 'test-delta' was not found
```

Comment: `sudo` without `-S` uses (and requires) `/dev/tty`. That is separate from stdin,out,err so all your different and creative ways of redirecting stdin,out have no effect on it. Nor does `setsid`, which (only) affects delivery of _signals_ from the tty driver, which are not relevant here. **I'm pretty sure docker _does_ affect /dev/tty and is your problem here**, but I don't use docker myself and don't know the correct fix.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't simply run `makepkg` as `root`?